# Performance impact of copying php variables

Tags: php, performance

Just wondering about the performance impact of copying very large php variables. For example say $arr is an enormous array. If I do $arr2 = $arr, is this a deep copy or is $arr2 merely a pointer to $arr like it is in Java? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *(reference)* Copy on Write in the PHP language: http://www.research.ibm.com/trl/people/mich/pub/200901_popl2009phpsem.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$arr2 = $arr` creates a deep copy.  But the actual copying only happens when $arr2 is modified -- PHP utilizes copy-on-write.

If you want a "pointer" instead of a copy, use `$arr2 =& $arr`, which makes $arr2 a reference to $arr.

Answer (score 1):

If you use $arr2 = &$arr ;

It will reference of the $arr .

Answer (score 1):

The general rule in PHP is don't create references unless you need the functionality they provide. References will only make the code slower otherwise.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php